# How to close the main window when a dialog appears

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qdialog

I was making a test program where the MainWindow serves as a login screen. User types in a username and password. If they match what the string is assigned to, then the Dialog appears. If it fails, a QMessageBox appears instead.

What my issue is when I want the Dialog to appear (the main program), I want the Login page to disappear. The Command close(); would just close everything.

Here is the code for the MainWindow.cpp (The Dialog is referenced in the header as a POINTER called mDialog)

```
 void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
 {
 if (ui->lineEdit->text() == username)
 {
    if (ui->lineEdit_2->text() == password)
    {
        //This is where the Dialog appears
        mDialog= new MyDialog(this);
        mDialog->show();
    }
}
else if (ui->lineEdit->text() != username || ui->lineEdit->text() ==NULL)
{
    if (ui->lineEdit_2->text() != password || ui->lineEdit_2->text() == NULL)
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "Error", "The username or password is incorrect.");
    }
 }
}
```

Here is the code for the main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Qt if the `parent` is destroyed, the `children` also, so if you go to this as a parameter to `MyDialog`, it will be destroyed. So that it is not destroyed do not pass the parent.

Change `mDialog= new MyDialog(this)` to `mDialog= new MyDialog()` and place `close()` after `show()`.

The function would look like:

```
...
mDialog= new QDialog();
mDialog->show();
close();
...
```

Comment: That actually makes sense. If it was to be done vise versa, let's say with the dialog being a login system and the main application being well...the main application, could it be done the same way? Or would this technique only work if the page is being passed as a pointer?

Comment: @JaoJao 
Please explain better, otherwise the best answer is to try.

Comment: Yeah I realized my explanation wasn't the greatest. I'll try before asking

Answer (score 3):

I think you should be showing the dialog as the login and the main window as the main program. If login is a success, show main window, not the other way around. Closing the main window is going to close the program.

I have done what you are trying to do. You can do what I said above or another option is to create a login screen in the main window using a QLabel. You can add an image to the Qlabel (a solid color image or anything you like) and make it the size of the window to block the view of the main program. Then you can add your line edits and buttons or anything you want. If login is successful, the image, labels and buttons can be closed to reveal the main program. I checked input using regular expressions.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but for some reason I couldn't get the main page to open as easy as the dialog since I can pass the dialog as a pointer. So I tried it vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Use `this->close()` to close the current window, but in the constructor of MyDialog, don't pass anything to the constructor. By default, the constructor will pass 0 to the parent argument, so as a result, the dialog will not have a parent.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If your main program is the Dialog you can before it have been shown open the login dialog with username/password fields.

Pseudocode for the main function (LoginDialog and MainDialog inherits QDialog):

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
LoginDialog lDialog;
lDialog.exec(); // Modal dialog behavior. Stopped at this line while it not closed (QDialog::close())
if (lDialog.getUsername() != username || lDialog.getPassword() != password)
{
  return 0;
}
MainDialog mDialog;
mDialog.show();
return a.exec();
```

Comment: The logic makes sense. Truly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what I did wrong, but for some reason the main.cpp isn't recognizing a boolean variable for a login.
I set a public boolean in the dialog header to false, and when the information is correct, it turns into true.

Now in the main.cpp, I have as shown
LoginDialog *log = new LoginDialog;
    log->show();
    if (log->login == true)
    {
        log->close();
        w.show();
    }

I'm unsure why it isn't recognizing the boolean variable

Answer (score 0):

You can set window visibility to false.

```
mainwindow.setVisible(false)
```

Comment: The setVisiblity() function does not exist, the most similar function is serVisible({boolean}).

Comment: it exists.this function inherited from `Qwidget`.